# Do I need a User CAL for a record in AD if the user is not authenticating?

Tags: active-directory, users, cal

We are considering expanding our user provisioning to cover a large portion of the workforce that does not currently exist in AD.  Our understanding is that any named user in AD requires a User CAL.  Is that correct even if the employee will not be authenticating or have an email address assigned to them?

Answer (score 0):

This question will likely get closed due to it being a duplicate, but maybe I can help you before that.

First, make sure you fact check anything told to you here with your Microsoft licensing rep.

> any named user in AD requires a User CAL

This isn't entirely accurate.  **You will need to purchase one CAL per user (living human being) that will be accessing the server(s) on your network.**  You will also need to consider which operating systems you already employ in your environment.  You need CALs specific to the operating system(s) running on your server(s) as well; meaning, if you have Server 2008 R2, your User CALs will need to be for that version, so make sure you haven't mixed and matched and messed things up.